# Using loop dynamically to set image in array

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop

```
int imgs[] =
    {
         R.drawable.a,
         R.drawable.b,
         R.drawable.c,
         R.drawable.d,
         R.drawable.e,
         // R.drawable.abc,
    };
```

I want to do that thing with the help of if loop.

Comment: Question is very unclear

Comment: `help of if loop` really?

Comment: sorry i want to assign drawable images dynamically rather than manual

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understood you correctly and what you're looking for is dynamic creation of that `array`.

For example, if your drawables are named like `R.drawable.image0`, `R.drawable.image1`, etc. And there are N of them you can use the following code.

```
int imgs[] = new int[N];
 
for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
    imgs[i] = this.getResources().getIdentifier("image" + i, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
}
```

**EDIT:**

Well, there's some confusion in the comment section.

If you want to keep your drawable names as they are (a, b, c) you would need to define them too. For example

```
String[] names = {"a", "b", "c"};
int imgs[] = new int[names.length];

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    imgs[i] = this.getResources().getIdentifier(names[i], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
}
```

But as you see, you're not achieving much by using that loop in this case, because you still have to manually type all the names.

Comment: that is the thing

Comment: may i know what is this package name?

Comment: Package name is the package of your application (for example com.example.app).

This line "this.getPackageName()" just assumes that "this" is a Context (or any descendant, like Activity).

Comment: My guess is that you copypasted this code as is and it's breaking down on you and that's because @Roman assumed that you have declared the N variable somewhere in the code, but apparently you didn't.

Comment: That was just an example of getting resource id by name.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is create a model class like this :

```
class DrawableClass{
    int id;
    Drawable drawable;
}
```

create objects of this with incremental **id** in each object. and in loop parse with respect to **id**.

Comment: and how they will take picture

Comment: for setting the picture in each object. You have to use getter and setter methods of the above mentioned class or create a constructor of this class which accept Drawable as paramter.